# Why can't i rename a symlink using rename() in c?

Tags: c, windows, symlink, mingw-w64

I have created a symlink using mklink command. I am linking a .txt file to a .exe file. But whenever i try to rename the symlink using rename() in c, the file is not renamed and also the .exe file it is linked to gets deleted.

Here is the command i am using -

```
mklink K:\ab\a.txt C:\call.exe
```

Here is the rename command i am using in my c program -

```
rename("K:\\ab\\a.txt","K:\\ab\\abc.txt");
```

Whenever the c program with rename command is executed, call.exe is deleted and also the symlink is not renamed instead a new file abc.txt is generated.

Comment: What is the return value of `rename` after you execute the above?

Comment: return value of `rename` is 0

Comment: So the symlink `K:\ab\a.txt` still exists after you call `rename` and you expected `abc.txt` to be a `symlink` instead of a `file`?  You didn't have a file named `K:\\ab\\a.txt`, did you?

Comment: Exactly. And no i don't have any file named  K:\\ab\\a.txt. There is only a symlink there